# Disqus Container (disqus_thread) element is missing.

Tags: disqus

I tried to integrate Disqus in my site, but it never displays, and on the console it says this:

```
DISQUS: Container (disqus_thread) element is missing.
```

I dug around for a while to understand what it means. The disqus_thread elements is definitely there, but for some reason it doesn't see it?

(This happens both on localhost, but also on the target web site if I deploy it with Disqus included.)

Answer (score 1):

Is the 'disqus_thread' DIV on the page? This should only happen if the following was missing:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

If it's there, post the source of the embed code on your site and that might reveal some more clues.